# java how can I build jar that connects with database

Tags: java, sql-server, jar, connection

I have a program that works with database sql server. I wanna build jar file of it. but the result is that it won't work where there will not be installed sql server. is there any way to build such jar with mdf file of the database which will work even if a user doesn't have sql server being installed?

Comment: connection with a database that will work if there is no database? I would be very, VERY, impressed if you manage to pull that one off.

Comment: What you want is an embedded database. SQL Server is not one of them. Your question is similar to "if I save the HTML page of Google on a USB key, and open it on a computer which has no Internet, will I be able to use Google?"

Comment: You can use an embedded database instead of a database server. You can ship an embedded database with your application and it will work everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Tell me, please, which embedded database you mean (Derby?). I'm a novice in this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file, which will create database, if your code is running first time and database doesn't exists.  You can run batch file using `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: How will it work if "User does not have SQL Server Installed" as OP asked?

Comment: In that case, it can be a embedded database as suggested by Aru.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want your application to be portable without those dependencies you should use an [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), like SQLite, for instance.